# Dropdown cascading fetch the selected value

Tags: reactjs, cascadingdropdown

I have a code as below in which am trying to implement dropdown cascading:-

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

class clusterServersDropdown extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            clusterslist:[],
            servertype:[],
            selectcluster:'',
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            clusterslist:[
                {label: "cluster1", servertype:["test1","test2","test3"]},
                {label: "cluster2", servertype:["test1","test2","test3"]},
            ]
        });
    }
    selectclusterChange(e){
        this.setState({selectcluster:e.target.value});
        this.setState({servertype: this.state.clusterslist.find(x => x.label===e.target.value).servertype })
    }

    routeChange = (e) => {
        console.log(this.state.selectcluster)
        console.log(this.state.servertype)
      };

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <center>
                    <h1>
                        Implement cascading Dropdown list
                        <h2>
                            ReactJS tutorials
                            <hr />
                                <select value={this.state.selectcluster} onChange={this.selectclusterChange.bind(this)}>
                                    <option>
                                        -- Select --
                                    </option>
                                    {this.state.clusterslist.map(x => {
                                        return <option>
                                            {x.label}
                                        </option>
                                    })}
                                </select>
                                <select value={this.state.servertype} onChange={this.routeChange}>
                                    <option>
                                    --------selection disabled------
                                    </option>
                                    {
                                        this.state.servertype.map(
                                            x => {
                                                return <option>
                                                    {x}
                                    </option>
                                            }
                                        )
                                    }
                                </select>
                        </h2>
                    </h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default clusterServersDropdown;
```

In this case, I am able to get output as below:-
[image]

Now I am able to print 1st level selected value and all other values of the other dropdown. Now let's say if I select test1 from the second dropdown, how can I fetch this selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need to be fixed;

1. You need to keep a state value for the selected server `selectserver`.

```
    this.state = {
      ...
      selectserver: "",
      ...
    };
```

2. The `routeChange` handler function should update `selectserver`.

```
  routeChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectserver: e.target.value });
  };
```

3. Server selection need to to `this.state.selectserver` as the value.

```
<select
     value={this.state.selectserver}
     onChange={this.routeChange}
>
  ...
  ...
</select>
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-elbakyan-eom5r?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Sarvesh Agarwal, check this out !!

Comment: Does the code sandbox work as you expect?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, its working fine. It was my mistake.

Comment: Hi one more thing, in your sandbox when I tried to access the value of the element using console.log it doesn't give me any value:-                   
      routeChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectserver: e.target.value }); console.log(this.state.selectserver)                                                                                     
  }; What happens is the value is printed when i select cluster once again and then the another dropdown value

Comment: My bad changed the code to 
  routeChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ selectserver: e.target.value}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.selectserver);
      });
  };